# XPath query off a XPath result and get childNodes HTML

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to get the HTML out of a jquery result also while being able to do a jquery off a result in PHP.

Here is the current code that I been using

```
 $url = 'http://www.foobar.com';
$output = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Supress Warnings for HTML5 conversion issue
$doc->loadHTML($output);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false); //Start Showing Errors

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


$CategoryString = '//tr[@class="playerSet"]';


$obj = new stdClass();

$x = 0;

foreach ($xpath->query($CategoryString) as $e) {

    $x++;
    $y = 0;
    foreach ($e->childNodes as $child) 
    { 

       $y++;
       if ($y == 1) $obj->players[$x]['name'] = $child->textContent;
       if ($y == 3) $obj->players[$x]['position'] = $child->textContent;
       if ($y == 5) $obj->players[$x]['team'] = $child->textContent;
       if ($y == 7) $obj->players[$x]['opp'] = $child->textContent;
    }
}


echo json_encode($obj);
```

Now this has been allowing me to cycle through the childNodes off the initial query.  However I want to make this more "refined" instead of just doing a cheap cycle.

How would I do another xpath->query off the $e so I can cycle through those in a foreach loop?

For example I want to do the query of ('//td') so i can do a foreach on the results of the //td off the initial query result ($e)

Last instead of displaying $child->textContent  how would I get the $child html?  I've tried searching online but I couldn't find a quick reference for what I COULD use in order to see the possible results.  Is there a way I can do an echo to see all the possible variables I can use off $child->  instead of textContent?  I tried nodeValue but I'm not getting the result i'm looking for

**EDIT - Found a way to get innerHTML of DOM through a function incase anyone is curious**

```
function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;

    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    return $innerHTML; 
}
```

Still looking for any help on doing the foreach off the $e using the example jquery.

**EDIT - For claification the reason I need to do the query off of $e**

One main reason is because in the "Name" column sometimes its duplicated so i only want to get the name by doing...

```
'//td/span'
```

off the main query.  I can't do this without doing another jquery off the main query's results

There may be more columns then just 'name' and then the output would be done as a JSON_ENCODE.   I've updated my example code to show more.

Comment: `$child html`? you mean an 'innerHTML' equivalent? no such thing directly in php dom, but there's lots of examples on how to simulate it. and every xpath query call can be given a "context" to operate on, which is simply a node/nodelist  that the new query should be restricted to.

Comment: yea innerHTML was what I was looking for, if thats not possible then at least knowing how to do a proper query off the $e would get me closer to being able to use the data the way I need to.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address the two questions you asked:

#### 1. How would I do another xpath->query off the $e?

It will be more efficient to do this in the original xpath query, like this:

```xml
//tr[@class="playerSet"]/td
```

This will give you a result for each *td* that has a *tr* parent of class *playerSet*.

However, if you want you can indeed do another query with a certain node as scope. The [DOMXPath *query* method](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) allows you to pass that node as second argument:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//tr') as $e) {
    foreach ($xpath->query('td', $e) as $child) {
        echo $child->textContent;
    } 
}
```

But in this case it is a bit overkill to use an XPath query for getting the `TD` children of a `TR` element. Using the `childNodes` property works fine as well (as table rows are not supposed to have any other children than `TD` elements), and is more efficient:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//tr') as $e) {
    foreach ($e->childNodes as $child) {
        echo $child->textContent;
    } 
}
```

#### 2. How would I get the $child html?

With the [saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) method:

```
$obj->players[$x]['innerHTML'] = $doc->saveHTML($e);
```

#### What might also interest you:

The docs on [XPath Location Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths):

> `child::*` selects all element children of the context node
>
> `child::text()` selects all text node children of the context node
>
> `child::node()` selects all the children of the context node, whatever their node type

You could for instance play with this:

```xml
//tr[@class="playerSet"]/child::node()
```

Or if you want to go through the whole tree of tags (not only next level):

```xml
//tr[@class="playerSet"]/descendant::node()
```

Comment: I know i could just do /td, but I need to be able to keep everything seperate since they are individual rows, and it would be really hard for me to keep track of a new "row" unless i get all the row's first, and then get each item out of each TD of the row. It would be best to be able to do the xpath query off the $e as mentioned above instead of trying to just do it off /td in the original. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Also as mentioned above in the original, there are sometimes when name or another column will have a specific <tag> that i only want to pull out of that so I would want to do a query off the results of $e so i can specify what information inside that $e child i want to actually look at.

Comment: I added an example in the first section about nested XPath queries.